# Keep getting the 'Cross-thread operation not valid' when trying to show the menustrip of a notifyicon

Tags: .net, multithreading, notifyicon, contextmenustrip

This is not a regular 'Corss-Thread opeartion' BS, so don't post the obvious solutions please.

This is something that's been driving me crazy for days now.

I have a `NotifyIcon`, with a binded `ContextMenuStrip`.
Everything works as it should, but sometimes (and I can't recall the exact steps to reproduce this) I get the cross-thread exception.
All my access to the `ContextMenuStrip`/`NotifyIcon` is padded with the Invoke cr*p, but still - when the user right-clicks on the notify icon - the exception is raised.

This is the full data from the exception:

`Message`: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

`Call stack`:

> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 
>   height, BoundsSpecified specified)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Location(Point value)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.Show(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip.ShowInTaskbar(Int32 x, Int32 y)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.ShowContextMenu()
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.WndProc(Message& msg)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon.NotifyIconNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.PeekMessage(MSG& msg, HandleRef hwnd, Int32 msgMin, Int32 msgMax, Int32 remove)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>
> at StarLIMS.Grabber.Manager.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\SDMS14SP2\StarLIMS.Grabber\StarLIMS.Grabber.Manager\Program.cs:line 34
>
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>
> at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Notice that the exception message is the exact message I get, the value inside the '' is empty

Comment: Is it possible that the NotifyIcon is being created on another thread than the main thread?

Comment: can you please post the **Invoke cr*p** you padded access to the `ContextMenuStrip/NotifyIcon` ?

Comment: What is happening when the user right clicks? Can we see that code?

Comment: @Doggett: Thanks for the enlightment - i'm creating the NotifyIcon under the OnLoad, instead of the constructor - I think this fixed it. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As Doggett pointed - my `ContextMenuStrip` was initialized under the OnLoad, instead of the ctor... once I moved it in the ctor - problem disappeared.

Comment: You've just ignored the problem.  The real one is that OnLoad was running on the wrong thread.  This is going to byte you in the ass sooner or later.  Set a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Sounds like "regular 'Corss-Thread opeartion' BS" to me. I won't "post the obvious solutions" on how you might go about fixing the threading problems, but you really should.